# Javascript find the difference between Chrome and Dolphin

Tags: javascript, android, browser, navigator

navigator.appName is the same all 3 of these browsers:

```
Netscape
```

navigator.vendor is the same all 3 of these browsers:

```
Google inc.
```

navigator.userAgent is the same on 2:

//Android default browser

```
'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-gb; GT-I9100 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30'
```

//Android Google Chrome

```
'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.2; GT-I9100 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.99 Mobile Safari/537.36'
```

//Android Dolphin Browser

```
'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.2; GT-I9100 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.99 Mobile Safari/537.36'
```

**How do I tell the difference between Chrome and Dolphin with javascript?**

Comment: Why are you trying to tell the difference?

Comment: they are not the same browser! one handles websockets

Comment: ah!  Now we come to what your question really is!  Asking another question about how to detect if websockets are available will be MUCH more useful.

Comment: No Mate! that is NOT my question!

Comment: I could answer the question because there is a way to do it. But it wouldn't be proper for your use case. What you are really after is this: [how to detect support for web sockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060320/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-websocket-support-using-javascript).