# Fake websocket function in Android browser

Tags: websocket

I want to run websocket in a browser to connect to a server, or use flash when ws is not available (like what websocket.js does)
but it seems there is a native WebSocket function in an android browser (not chrome), the function has member functions such as close, send etc but it does not work. I can't capture any ws packages on the router when trying to use the native ws to connect to a server.
So,

1. why the fake ws function exists .........
2. I'll try to check binaryType of this object, when binaryType is undefined or "" I think it is not a good ws (including ws ver 7-8, servers support only ws ver 13). Is this exact? or anyway better? UserAgent may be a not good idea, because there are lots of custom browsers on android (such as firefox, dolphin, ...), and there is not a good key word to check in UA
3. when or in which version will the fake ws function of android browser disappear or become real? Although google recommands chrome, but some phones seem running default browser with an icon like the earth instand of chrome.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Google started work on implementing WebSocket in the Android browser, but only got as far as the API.

The fake API exists across all newer versions of the Android browser, irrespective of vendor. This only changes with Android 4.4, where the Android browser has been replaced with Chrome.

I would not suggest detecting this by user agent or like, but instead detect through the behavior of the fake WS object.

E.g. when opening a trial WebSocket connection, the 'readystate' on the Android browser WebSocket object always remains at '0', whereas with a working implementation it changes.

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060320/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-websocket-support-using-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Android are you using?

According to [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/websockets), the only Android browser that supports Websockets is the 4.4.

Cheers.

Comment: thanks a lot. as i know, only a few phones has fake ws, such as galaxy s3/gt-i9300 running 4.1.2. may i find fake ws from real ones by binarytype?